# Golang Runtime recompile

Tags: go

Well ,I sooooo flesh for the Golang . And I get a mission to recompile the Golang 's runtime via this [blog](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/11/docker-insane-scale-on-ibm-power-systems/).

`One way is to change this default number in the GO runtime (GCC-GO or GC) and recompile the runtime. In proc.go, you can change the line sched.maxmcount = 10000 to a number that is appropriate.`

#### First: recompile the whole golang.

I follow this [Installing Go from source](https://golang.org/doc/install/source) ,and execute this cmd：

`./all.bash`

Output is :

```
Building Go bootstrap tool.
cmd/dist
import cycle not allowed
package cmd/dist
    imports bytes
    imports errors
    imports runtime
    imports runtime/internal/atomic
    imports unsafe
    imports runtime
```

It seems everything work well, but while I check about the `go` cmd，it's the same. Also ,I can't find any change to bin or pkg dir.

#### Then ,try to build pkg

`go install src/runtime`

Also, it doesn't come out any error and I can't find any target build.

I  have no any idea how to do it  :(

Any suggestion well so appresiate !

Comment: `all.bash` is all you need to build all.

Comment: Building will put the output in the first directory in your Go path + ./src/go/bin/go, this will need to be on your path in front of wherever your bootstrap Go install lives. It may also put the binaries in $GOBIN if set, IIRC.

Comment: @SamWhited: no it won't. Stdlib packages are special cased, and installed in GOROOT.

Comment: @JimB if you have goroot set, but you really shouldn't: http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really

Comment: @SamWhited: no, GOROOT is implied whether you set it or not (look at the output of `go env GOROOT`, and yes, you should not set it). You can see the see the output from my example (or use `-x` if you want everything), and check the timestamp on `GOROOT/pkg/GOOS_GOARCH/runtime.a`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Looks like I was wrong about the path though; you're correct. I changed my GOPATH and it still put it where the previous source was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You install packages by their import path, so you don't use the `src/` prefix.

To recompile the runtime package, use:

```
$ go install -a -v runtime
runtime/internal/sys
runtime/internal/atomic
runtime
```